# Preserve text case when replacing based on case-insensitive search?

Tags: android, replace, textview

In my app I have a Textview with some text. I'm trying to get an input from the user, and then highlight words in the Textview according to that input.

For instance if the text is

> Hello stackoverflow

and the input for the user is

> hello

I want to replace the text with:

```
<font color='red'>Hello</font>` stackoverflow
```

This is my code:

```
String input = //GETTING INPUT FROM THE USER
text= text.replaceAll(input,"<font color='red'>"+input+"</font>");
Textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

And the replacement is working, but the problem is that my current code changes the original word cases, for example :

**Text:** HeLLo stackoverflow

**Input:** hello

**What i get:** `<font color='red'>hello</font>` stackoverflow

**What i want:** `<font color='red'>HeLLo</font>` stackoverflow

Comment: james please i still dont get you, what do you mean by highlight and your various example? caps?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear , I'm working on a kind of a search thing in a large text , The user enters a word--->the app is looking for it in the text -->and last , displaying the same text but now with the searched word highlighted . something like this : http://hugoware.net/resource/blog/search-highlight/whatbrowser-full.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to think about regular expressions.

`replaceAll` allows you to use regular expressions, and so, you can replace the text for the exact occurrence that was found. 
For instance if Hello was found, it replaces it for `<font color='red'>Hello</font>`. 
If HeLLo is found, it replaces it for `<font color='red'>HeLLo</font>`

Your code should be somehing as easy as:

```
String highlighted = text.replaceAll("(?i)("+input+")","<font color='red'>$1</font>");
```

This means:

- `(?i)` : i want to search for something, case insensitive
- `"("+input+")"` : input is betwen `(` and `)` because we are creating a group, so this group can be refered later
- `"<font color='red'>$1</font>"` : instead of replacing by input, that would change the case, we replace it by `$1, that is the reference to the first matched group. This means that we  want to replace it using the exact word that was found.

But please, try it and keep playing since regular expressions are tricky.

### Other reads

It is easier and more clear if you use the `Pattern`class.

You can read more here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Also, you can take a look at how to do it:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

```
public String replaceAll(String regex,  String replacement)
```

.
    Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.
    An invocation of this method of the form str.replaceAll(regex, repl) yields exactly the same result as the expression

```
Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)
```

Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.

```
Parameters:
regex - the regular expression to which this string is to be matched
replacement - the string to be substituted for each match
Returns:
The resulting String
```

**UPDATE**

You can test your regular expressions in this page:

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Maybe consider using `Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)...`

Comment: Hi , thank you for your reply , I'm a little bit confused could you please provide me an example of combining these two?

Comment: I think that  `holder=holder.replaceAll("("+input+")", "<font color='red'>$1</font>"); Textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(holder));`will be enough. I cannot try it now. With Pattern will be something like `holder=Pattern.compile("("+input+")",, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(holder).replaceAll("$1")`

Comment: Also this code highlights ALL occurrences, and not only the first one! Give it a try with a text that has the word more than once

Comment: Currently , this code doesn't highlight anything maybe I'm doing something wrong? ,of course more than a once highlighting would be preferred.

Comment: could you paste the full code your are using for this?

Comment: my full code is a little bit long and complicated to understand but the original highlighting part of my code is :                           text= text.replaceAll("(?i)" + input,"<font color='red'>"+input+"</font>");                                     Textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));

Comment: And that code is working, but with with the problem you described?

Comment: yes. the only problem is that the highlighted word will use the same cases as the input (like in the question's example )

Comment: try `text= text.replaceAll("(?i)(" + input+")","<font color='red'>$1</font>"); Textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));`

Comment: @CarlosRobles Carlos you are a true magician!, that group trick was the catch